Extract multiple bands into one image with rasterio
I want to extract a set of images from Sentinel-2 L2A, containing 12 bands, all resampled to 10 m/pixel, in .tiff file format.
The code is composed of parts taken from this documentation mainly composed of 2 functions, one for the request of the bands & satellite specifications, and one for the specification of resolution, time interval in which the images will be taken and AOIs.
I want to resample all 12 bands to 10 m/pixel, and the use the rasterio library to stack them in order to eventually get an image with 12 all these specifications.
The part of the code which is of interest is the following:
def get_all_bands_request(time_interval, bbox, size, config):

    evalscript_all_bands = """
        //VERSION=3
        function setup() {
            return {
                input: [{
                    bands: ["B01","B02","B03","B04","B05","B06","B07","B08","B8A","B09","B11","B12"],
                    units: "DN"
                }],
                output: {
                    bands: 12,
                    sampleType: "INT16"
                }
            };
        }

        function evaluatePixel(sample) {
            return [sample.B01,
                    sample.B02,
                    sample.B03,
                    sample.B04,
                    sample.B05,
                    sample.B06,
                    sample.B07,
                    sample.B08,
                    sample.B8A,
                    sample.B09,
                    sample.B11,
                    sample.B12];
        }
    """

    return SentinelHubRequest(
        evalscript=evalscript_all_bands,
        input_data=[
            SentinelHubRequest.input_data(
                data_collection=DataCollection.SENTINEL2_L2A.define_from(
                    "s2l2a", service_url=config.sh_base_url
                ),
                time_interval=time_interval,
                mosaicking_order=MosaickingOrder.LEAST_CC
            )
        ],
        responses=[SentinelHubRequest.output_response("default", MimeType.TIFF)],
        bbox=bbox,
        size=size,
        config=config,
    )

def processing(locations, config):
    resolution = 10 # Meters per pixel

    start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
    end = datetime.datetime(2023, 12, 31)
    n_chunks = 10
    tdelta = (end - start) / n_chunks
    edges = [(start + i * tdelta).date().isoformat() for i in range(n_chunks)]
    slots = [(edges[i], edges[i + 1]) for i in range(len(edges) - 1)]

    for loc_idx, coords in enumerate(locations):
        print(f"Processing location {loc_idx + 1}/{len(locations)}")

        bbox = BBox(bbox=coords, crs=CRS.WGS84)
        size = bbox_to_dimensions(bbox, resolution=resolution)

        list_of_requests = [
            get_all_bands_request(slot, bbox, size, config)
            for slot in slots
        ]
        list_of_requests = [request.download_list[0] for request in list_of_requests]

        data = SentinelHubDownloadClient(config=config).download(
            list_of_requests, max_threads=5
        )

        for idx, image in enumerate(data):
            image_path = f'imagepath'

            transform = from_bounds(*coords, size[0], size[1])
            raster_crs = RasterioCRS.from_epsg(4326)

            with rasterio.open(
                image_path,
                "w",
                driver="GTiff",
                height=image.shape[0],
                width=image.shape[1],
                count=image.shape[2],
                dtype=image.dtype,
                crs=raster_crs,
                transform=transform,
            ) as dst:
                for band in range(image.shape[2]):
                    dst.write(image[:, :, band], band + 1)

        print(f"Processing of location {loc_idx + 1}/{len(locations)} completed")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    locations = [
        (23.47023,37.728482,23.706436,37.915013),
    ]

    processing(locations, config)


Problem is, the .tiff files i get are black, what am I missing?

Int16 has a large value range and often data falls to the lower end of the range. That makes the image appears black if it is rendered without contrast enhancement. Check the image statistics and histogram.

I imported the files through SNAP and it worked just fine, they did not appear black.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
